# PlusShare class is deprecated. Is there any other alternative to share on google Plus from android app?

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to integrate Google plus in my android app and share a post from my app to Google Plus. For that, I am following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/) of it. In that documentation, the following code is given to share on google plus :

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
      .setType("text/plain")
      .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
      .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
      .getIntent();

  startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```

But, the problem is `PlusShare` class is deprecated. So, My question is, **Is there any other method or another way to share a post on Google Plus?**

> Note: Sharing post from my app is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another way of doing it.
that is in the following way.

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                .setText("your Text")
                .setType("text/plain")
                .getIntent()
                .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

startActivityForResult(shareIntent, GOOGLE_REQUEST_SHARE);
```